# Is there a way to import modules in React without create-react-app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've just started using react and was using the create-react-app from npm until today. I've gotten the react and reactdom code from

```
https://unpkg.com/react@15/dist/react.js
https://unpkg.com/react-dom@15/dist/react-dom.js
```

I've saved the files as:

```
/Test/react/react.js
/Test/react/react-dom.js
```

This is my index.js:

```
<!--/Test/index.js-->

<html>

<head>
    <title>React Hello World</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="root"></div>

    <script src="react/react.js"></script>
    <script src="react/react-dom.js"></script>
    <script src="App.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

I have created a module called Greetings, given below:

```
//Test/Components/Greetings.js

class Greetings extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return React.createElement(
      "h1",
      null,
      "Greetings, " + this.props.name + "!"
    );
  }
}

export default Greetings;
```

And I've created an App.js, given here:

```
//Test/App.js

import Greetings from "./Components/Greetings";

ReactDOM.render(
  React.createElement(Greetings, { name: "Me" }),
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

Is there an easy way to import a react module?

Comment: please follow this blog https://dev.to/vish448/create-react-project-without-create-react-app-3goh

Comment: but this uses npm, which is what i dont have or want. But thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`import` and `export` are Node.js keywords.  On the client-side you don't need them.  Simply include your javascript files in the html:

```
<script src="App.js"></script>
<script src="Greetings.js"></script>
```